# How to converting an alarm to ultrasound emitter?

Tags: ultrasound, transducer

I've heard that it's much more cost effective to convert alarms to ultrasonic emitters vs outright buying ultrasound transducers.

How would you go about tackling such a project?

Comment: If you've heard something somewhere, then please provide a reference to where you've heard it.

Comment: It was a buddy that worked with Tesla coils quite a bit who died a couple years ago. He dabbled in ultrasound tech as well, but I never got any details from him since I wasn't interested at the time. He was great at repurposing old equipment and said that "alarms make great ultrasonic transducers." Of course hindsight's always 20/20 right? :'(

Comment: I would first check what is the frequency range of ultrasound, then read the specs of an alarm speaker to check what its frequency range capability is.

Comment: A simple SRF04 US distance sensor is < $1 from China. Would your alarm transmitter be cheaper?

Comment: @Wouter  Are we talking cheap per instrument, or cheap per Watt of sound power.  Which makes me wonder.  Why does the O.P. want to make ultrasound?  What is the O.P. trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Nick I dunno, but I doubt that a transducer from some random alarm will be better than one from some random chinese hobby product :)

Comment: You may be right. I just found a 1.6MHz transducer for $8 USD so that's pretty reasonable. I guess the question would evolve to being able to control the frequency and amplitude at this point for such a device. An actual sensor that would go up to that range in order to graph it (freq+amplitude) onscreen in realtime would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @ylluminate  1.6MHz will travel only a very short distance in air.  [See here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52195/ultrasonic-wave-through-air) for more details.

Comment: Right, so for you would only get a short distance for something >1MHz. In this application I think I need to figure out how to drive such a transducer at 200KHz to 800KHz, which would yield a little more distance, but distance isn't a key factor.